# Is Normal centralizer problem in P?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms

**Notations**

1. $\le$ is used for subgroup
2. $G = \langle A \rangle  $ means group $G$ is generated by set $A$
3. $P$ means polynomial time in input size.
4. $\Omega = \{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$ is a input domain
5. Sym($\Omega$) means symmetric group on $\Omega$

---

**Given:** $G = \langle A \rangle, H = \langle B \rangle \le \text{Sym}(\Omega)$, where $G$ normalizes $H$.

**Find :** $C_G(H) = \{g \in G \mid gh =hg, \forall h \in H\}$

---

**Question :** Is it in $P$? Give an polynomial time algorithm if answer is yes. I know that If we drop the normal condition from the above problem then problem will not be in $P$. Also note that computing normaliser of subgroup $H$ is in P.

Comment: How are elements of A represented? ​ ​

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Is the Normal centralizer problem in P?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/290941)